# Has anyone experience in running SAP jobs with Rundeck

Tags: jobs, scheduling, rundeck, sap-basis

We have a requirement that we need to replace the UC4 with Rundeck for job scheduling.

Is there a Rundeck support SAP?

Please let me know if anyone is having experience in this. I have searched a lot but nothing useful found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at [this](https://github.com/target/plugin-for-rundeck-to-execute-sap-modules). It's an (unofficial) Rundeck plugin to run SAP modules. If you want some specific functionality you can contact the author to suggest expand the plugin.

Also, you can design a [workflow](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/job-workflows.html#job-workflows) that [calls](https://developers.sap.com/tutorials/hcp-abh-test-locally.html#a036e41b-34cf-4d69-bd77-1e7bae752ae0) SAP API.